# Read-Host always ends in a colon

Tags: windows, powershell

Whenever I do a `Read-Host` the prompt always ends in `:` is there anyway to change this? is it -Prompt Flag?

Comment: No, the `: ` that you're seeing is added by the host application (in your case probably `powershell.exe`, `powershell_ise.exe`)

Comment: Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: Again, it's entirely up to the host application how the `Read-Host` call get's rendered in the UI, so yes - by writing your own host application instead of using `powershell.exe`.

Comment: I think you can also use a write-host without a colon, then a read host with no -prompt and it shouldn't show the colon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to control how the executing host application presents the prompt when passing a `Prompt` message parameter argument.

What you can do instead, is call `$Host.UI.ReadLine()` directly from your script and prepend a message yourself:

```
Write-Host "No colons here>" -NoNewLine
$UserInput = $Host.UI.ReadLine()
```

Here's an example of what that looks like in `powershell.exe`:

[image: Read-HostCustom function]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you use to capture that gif?

Comment: Jus to addon to @TheIncorrigible1... FYI... Camtsaia will do .gifs as well, but that cost money, but this one is open source: ScreenToGif.com

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley LICEcap

Answer (score 0):

**To semi-permanently rid PowerShell's Read-Host of its default colon**, override the native Read-Host cmdlet with your own function of the same name as follows:

```
function Read-Host($prompt) {
  Write-Host "$prompt  " -NoNewline
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Read-Host }
```

**Result:**

```
Read-Host "What is your name?"
    
What's your name?  Mike
Mike
```

Either place that function at the top of your script or save it in a module and import it in each script as needed.

Hope this helps.

~Mike